# Is there a concept of POD types in Rust?

Tags: rust

In C++, the term *POD type* is used to describe types which only contain *plain old data*. [Quoted from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146452/what-are-pod-types-in-c):

> A class [...] without constructors, destructors and virtual members functions.

Is there a similar concept in Rust?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Quick answer; **C++'s POD types ≈ Rust's [`Copy` types](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/marker/trait.Copy.html)**.

However, there are a few other, related concepts. Let's discuss them in detail!

---

The **`Copy` trait** is closest to the term "POD type" in C++ and is defined as follows:

> Types whose values can be duplicated simply by copying bits.

By "copying bits", the documentation basically means `memcpy()`. This includes all primitive types, such as `u32`, `f32`, `char` and `bool`, but user defined types can be `Copy`, too. Usually the trait is simply *derived*:

```
#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
struct Point {
    x: f32,
    y: f32,
}
```

You might have noticed the `Clone`: the [**`Clone` trait**](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/clone/trait.Clone.html) is a requirement of `Copy` and is defined as:

> A common trait for the ability to explicitly duplicate an object.

`Clone` says that a type is "somehow able to duplicate itself" and `Copy` requires more by saying the type is "able to duplicate itself by just copying the type's bits".

---

The C++ answer states that POD types don't contain "constructors, destructors and virtual members functions". Let's break that down for Rust:

- **Constructors**: Rust doesn't have dedicated constructor methods, but instead uses associated functions (static methods in C++). Every type, even all `Copy` types, may have as many associated functions and methods as they want. In Rust it is not really a requirement to be "POD". In particular, even Rust's primitive types have many methods, like [`u32::pow()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.u32.html#method.pow). This restriction doesn't apply to Rust.
- **Destructors**: in Rust, objects are destructed by calling [`drop()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/trait.Drop.html#tymethod.drop) from the `Drop` trait (or rather: `drop()` is automatically called at the end of scope). **Types can't be `Copy` when they implement the `Drop` trait!** Rust has a similar restriction here.
- **Virtual member functions**: in Rust, *virtual* is not a property of a function. Most functions can be used in a *virtual context*, that is: they can be used with dynamic dispatch, but being `Copy` doesn't prevent a type from being used in a dynamic dispatch context (in Rust terms: being used as trait object). This is partly thanks to the fact that the vptr is not stored within the type, but next to the pointer to the object (*fat pointers*). This point doesn't apply to Rust.

---

However, you might require more things from your "POD types" than "being copyable by copying bits". Rust has built-in, specific trait bounds for some additional properties:

- **`'static`**: requires that the type does not contain any internal references. For example, `struct Foo<'a>(&'a u32);` would not satisfy this trait bound. If you know your type is `'static`, you have no lifetime restrictions and the borrow checker won't make you any problems.
- [**`Sized`**](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/marker/trait.Sized.html): requires that the type has a size known at compile time and can thus be stored on the stack. That is true for almost all types; there are only a few rare-ish exceptions: `[T]` and `str` (slices), `dyn MyTrait` (trait objects) and structs that contain an unsized types as the last field (e.g. [`Path`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/path/struct.Path.html)).
- [**`Send`**](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/marker/trait.Send.html) and [**`Sync`**](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/marker/trait.Sync.html): require that the type can be sent to other threads and can shared via immutable reference (`&T`) across threads. Both traits are implemented for almost all types. It's not implemented if the type contains some kind of magic (e.g. [interior mutability](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cell/index.html), [references to something without having a lifetime](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/rc/struct.Rc.html), ...). Requiring those two trait bounds makes sure that your type does not have this magic.

So if you really want a **very simple, no-magic "bag of bits" type**, this seems like a fitting trait/collection of bounds:

```
trait Pod: 'static + Copy + Sized + Send + Sync {}

impl<T: 'static + Copy + Sized + Send + Sync> Pod for T {}
```

With those kinds of type, you won't deal with move semantics (due to `Copy`) or the borrow checker (due to `'static`).